# Azure Function App - trying to publish to a v1 function app from v2 tooling

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-function-app

I've created and successfully tested a Function App.
It requires the .net Framework because of a legacy library, and is set to use run-time version ~1. Publishing directly from Visual Studio 2017 using the publishing profile works normally. However, attempting to publish with the Azure CLI is giving me grief.

Following the MS article here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-azure-function-azure-cli

- azure-cli v2.0.64
- azure-functions-core-tools@2.7.1158  (npm)
- .NET Framework 4.8 DevPack

```
>func azure functionapp publish <myApp>
You're trying to publish to a v1 function app from v2 tooling.
You can pass --force to force update the app to v2, or downgrade to v1 tooling for publishing
```

How can I downgrade my tools?

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: I solved it with your advice!

Comment: Recieved exact same error while publishing from v2 tool to v3. The error message isn't dynamic, but installing v3 tool solved it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools#windows) seems to be that you need to install lower version like

To install v1 with npm:

```
npm i -g azure-functions-core-tools@1
```

The other way would be simply using msbuild

```
"msbuild.exe" "SOLUTIONNAME_OR_PROJECT"  /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site" /p:platform="any cpu" /p:configuration="release" /p:VisualStudioVersion="15.0"
```

This will produce zip with you azure function

Comment: Plain as day!  Specifying version 1 of the azure-functions-core-tools works perfectly. Thank you so much for the very clear and precise answer.