# Azure Function App - How to obtain the Invoke Url and code

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cli, azure-function-app

I've created and successfully tested a Function App that requires the .net Framework because of a legacy library, and is set to use run-time version ~1. I'm looking for the Invoke Url and code, to help automate deployment.

Following this [MS article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-azure-function-azure-cli#deploy-the-function-app-project-to-azure) and using the *azure-functions-core-tools v2* (`npm i -g azure-functions-core-tools@^2`),  I ***can*** see the *Invoke Url* when publish is called with the `--verbose` option.

However, because of the .net Framework requirement and run-time version ~1, we're bound to *azure-functions-core-tools v1* (`npm i -g azure-functions-core-tools@^1`) ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56121174/azure-function-app-trying-to-publish-to-a-v1-function-app-from-v2-tooling)). Executing any of the commands from func azure functionapp does’t include the Invoke Url. The `--verbose` option is not available.

```
>func azure functionapp publish <MyApp>

Getting site publishing info...
Publish C:\<MyProject> contents to an Azure Function App. Locally deleted files are not removed from destination.
Creating archive for current directory...
Uploading archive...
Upload completed successfully.
```

Same for `list-functions`

```
>func azure functionapp list-functions <MyApp>

Functions in <MyApp>:
    FunctionOne - [httpTrigger]
    FunctionTwo - [httpTrigger]
```

I haven't tried ARM yet.

Is there a way to obtain the **Invoke Url** for Function Apps on run-time version ~1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get the Invoke Url and the code with the following Azure CLI commands:

```
FUNCTION_CODE=$(az functionapp function keys list -g ${SOLUTION_NAME} -n $FUNCTIONS_NAME --function-name DPSCustomAllocationFunction --query "default")
FUNCTION_CODE=$(echo "$FUNCTION_CODE" | tr -d '"') #Remove "" from result
FUNCTION_URL=$(az functionapp function show --function-name DPSCustomAllocationFunction --resource-group $SOLUTION_NAME --query "invokeUrlTemplate" --output tsv --name $FUNCTIONS_NAME)
FUNCTION_URL=$(echo $FUNCTION_URL|tr -d '\r\n') #Remove breaklines from result
INVOKE_FUNCTION="$FUNCTION_URL?code=$FUNCTION_CODE"
```

Comment: I'm marking this as the solution, since it included @MarkusMeyer 's response and wrapped it up with a bow.  Much appreciated guys!

Answer (score 1):

Yo could use the REST API to get it:[List Function Secrets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/listfunctionsecrets), it will response the secret and triggerUrl.

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}/functions/{functionName}/listsecrets?api-version=2016-08-01
```

Also you could implement it with the PowerShell [GetFunctionInvokeUrl](https://github.com/davidebbo/AzureWebsitesSamples/blob/a0e948e217b7c318e28390bc81ca1c211e6c7991/PowerShell/HelperFunctions.ps1#L388-L393) to do it.

Comment: sorry haven't had a chance to test yet.  will update ASAP.

Comment: sorry for the late reply.  I haven't come back to this ticket for a while.  Currently I can't call ARM, I don't have the credentials to access our corporate subscription..

Comment: Worth noting that `listsecrets` will not work by default with runtime V2. It will if you change the storage type for secrets to `file`, but you shouldn't. Use `listkeys` and API version `2018-11-01` for V2 runtime now that the API actually supports retrieving keys from blob storage.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli):

[az functionapp function show](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp/function?view=azure-cli-latest#az_functionapp_function_show)

```
az functionapp function show --function-name MyFunction --name MyApp --resource-group MyResourceGroup --query "invokeUrlTemplate" --output tsv
```

Comment: Thanks for this Markus, it definitely led to the solution I needed.